# TrainReservation Schema not working

Tags: google-schemas

Below is the json script i am using to create a Train Reservation Schema, 
This is validated by Email Markup Tester by Google, but i am not able to see the Google now 
card appearing on my phone?

Does any body has any example of TrainReservation Schema ?

**Html :**

```
    <html>
<head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Script :**

```
   <script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "TrainReservation",
 "reservationNumber" : "2065784893",
 "modifyReservationUrl":"http://www.xyz.com/buytickets/myaccounthomepage.aspx",

 "reservationFor": {
   "@type": "TrainTrip",
   "name" : ": LONDON TERMINALS to MANCHESTER STNS",
   "description": "Departs 11:40 from LONDON TERMINALS  Arrives 13:49 to MANCHESTER STNS",
   "departureTime":"2013-12-17T14:20:03-08:00",
   "arrivalTime":"2013-12-17T13:20:03-08:00",
   "departureStation":"LONDON STNS",
   "arrivalStation":"MANCHESTER STNS",
   "trainCompany":"VIRGIN TRAINS"
 },

"creator":{
"@type":"Person",
"name":"H Walia",
"email":"abc@example.com"
},

 "price" : "28.05",
 "modifyReservationUrl" : "http://help.xyz.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3583",
 "seat" : "ADVANCE SINGLE",
 "bookingDate":"2013-12-17T09:21:03-08:00",
 "bookingTime":"2013-12-17T09:20:03-08:00",
 "numSeats" : "1",
 "ticketDownloadUrl" : "http://www.xyz.com",
 "ticketPrintUrl" : "http://www.xyz.com"

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Train reservations are not yet supported in Google Now: https://developers.google.com/schemas/now/cards#supported_schemas

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I though Train schema is the extensoion of EventReservation  https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/types/TrainReservation

Answer (score 1):

That reservation is for 2012. Try something with a departure time in the near future.

Comment: Thanks, i did tried updating datetime fields and corrected other tags, 
also this is validated with google email markup tester, but still not able to see any card on my google now ?
any idea's what is wrong missing ?

Comment: Did you send the email to yourself using the same email address as the sender and receiver? Also, do you have a closing </script> tag?

Comment: yes, i am using apps-script-tutorial. which sends email to my own account, also i </script> tag is there i have pasted full html i am using in mail_template to send the email ? also i am using iphone 4 to test it, if there is any compatibility issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I confused this with FlightReservation which is supported. Train reservations are not shown yet in Google Now.